# Action Script 3 - Events between Spark and Custom Components

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flex4

We are building an interface for a game.

The interface has a tabbed menu at the bottom of the screen, with each tab displaying different aspects of an object (called a node).

When you click on one of these parts, it becomes the focus, and we download it's details in XML, including all it's sub-nodes and parent nodes and then update the tab display accordingly, or at least that's what we'd like to happen.

What we have:

MainInterface.mxml

```
<s:Application...
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    public var currentNode:Node = new Node();

    protected function selectNodeHandler(event:Event):void
      {
        loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(ourWebSite + event.target.id + ".xml"))
        //the xmlDownloaded function below is what changes the contents of currentNode
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlDownloaded);
...
<s:SkinnableContainer  id="dashBoard"..
  <mx:TabNavigator...
    <s:NavigatorContent...
      <s:SkinnableDataContainer ...
        dataProvider="{currentNode.children}"
        itemRenderer="renderers.NodeRenderer">
```

Node.as (valueObjects.Node)

```
...
  [Bindable] public var id:String;
  [Bindable] public var name:String;
  [Bindable] public var children:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
  [Bindable] public var parents:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
...
```

NodeRenderer.mxml (renderers.NodeRenderer)

```
<s:ItemRenderer ... click="nodeRenderer_clickHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    protected function nodeRenderer_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
      var eventObject:Event = new Event ("nodeSelected");
      dispatchEvent(eventObject);
    }
 ...
 <s:Label text = "{data.name}"/>
```

We tried adding an event listener for "selectNode" to the dashBoard:SkinnableContainer you see see above, but it didn't seem to want to take. We suspect this is because dashBoard is from a spark component and the dispatcher for "selectNode" is on of our own custom components, but we weren't sure... in any case that's what the code assist seemed to indicate as we had to write it in by hand.

We're not sure how to pick up the Events in FlashBuilder 4's debugger, so we're having trouble working out where it's going wrong. Basically, when someone clicks on the label of a child or parent node (that is displayed by the itemRenderer), we want a URLRequest sent to our website, with the url specific to the node clicked on. We then want a URLLoader listening for the return which will update public variable 'currentNode' when xmlDownloaded is called by the loader.

If you could clarify how the click event should be dispatched, what should be listening for it then sending the URLRequest and where the URLLoader that is listening for the xml data to return should be that would solve our problems. Alternatively, if there is a better (more conventional) way to be doing what we're trying to do that would also help, as we're relatively new to actionscript and flex.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected function selectNodeHandler(url:String):void
  {
    loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(url));

    //consider identifying the loader, for instance
    loader.name = url; // you could also pass a second parameter 
    //to the function and assign it to the name property of the loader.

    //the xmlDownloaded function below is what changes the contents of currentNode
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlDownloaded);
  }


 protected function nodeRenderer_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
     var url:String = ourWebSite + event.currentTarget.id + ".xml";
     selectNodeHandler( url );
 }

 protected function xmlDownloaded( event:Event ):void
 {
      //identify the target here with the name property
      var id:String = event.target.name;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! We had to change
    selectNodeHandler(url);
to
    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.selectNodeHandler(url);
because the NodeRenderer file was unable to access the function otherwise, but otherwise that worked.

Comment: Also, we were under the impression you were meant to use events for everything as it provided for better encapsulation than going with method calls.Are events just not flexible enough, or will it take years before we're good enough to use them everywhere?

Comment: I didn't check the scope of the selectNodeHandler method when writing my answer, but you're right if the method is not within the calling object scope , you should use Events instead of calling the method directly as you do now. There are a few ways to handle this, in your case , you may be able to listen to the MouseEvent bubbling up to the top level and call the selectNodeHandler method from there. Alternatively, you can dispatch a custom event which would take , the url & loader id as parameters...